# Debugging / displaying errors in WP_Widget->form()

Tags: widgets, errors

I'm finding that if I have errors in my code that's being called by my custom widget's form() method, I don't see any error display - the only indication I have is that in Admin > Appearance > Widgets the sidebars are all gone.

What can be done to:
a) avoid completely destroying all sidebars in Admin whenever your code has an error
b) get more information about what is causing the error or exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the question was asked in May, the WP core team released the [Admin Debug Bar](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-bar/), and its ancillary plugin [Debug Bar Console](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-bar-console/) is exactly the balm to ease any WP Programmer's pain.

Comment: This doesn't actually answer the question. How do I see the contents of $instance, for, uh, instance?

Answer (score 0):

Here ya go

http://andrewnacin.com/2010/04/23/5-ways-to-debug-wordpress/

Comment: See my edit of a)